# How to destructure an interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am making a request as follow:

```js
const listCompartmentsRequest: identity.requests.ListCompartmentsRequest = {
  compartmentId: id,
  compartmentIdInSubtree: true,
}
```

But I would like to short that long line `identity.requests.ListCompartmentsRequest`.

I'm expecting something like that:

```js
const { ListCompartmentsRequest } = identity.requests

const listCompartmentsRequest: ListCompartmentsRequest = {
  compartmentId: id,
  compartmentIdInSubtree: true,
}
```

I tried it, however, I'm getting this error:

> `ListCompartmentsRequest` refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean `typeof ListCompartmentsRequest`?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MDN documentation for [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack **values** from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Destructuring only applies to values, not types — TypeScript does not currently offer any equivalent kind of syntax. Instead, you can create a new [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) that represents the nested member of the type that you described. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJhAdsAlqKBeKBvAUFKAJQgEcBXCAZ2EoC4d8CoAZFagYQHsBbMAQwBOwbkhrFyVYPTxMmAYx78hI5PHrUBKRAHMA3I1kLeg4aPgxEAZTIAjYAIgR6NzpwA2EPon2yAvj6h-XCDcUEgWNmAuY2VRSnEKakxYBGQ0EABtAHIEyUosgF1s1g5FExUxUkTgQv1cBUQklDhkrIBGACYAZiy6hqS3SOilU2R4qsl6Eqiy2LHcpKwZKCMRirUoZoAaRlXyszgLazsHJyh7Ch2goA)

```ts
type Identity = {
  Requests: {
    ListCompartmentsRequest: {
      compartmentId: string;
      compartmentIdInSubtree: boolean;
    };
  };
};

type ListCompartmentsRequest = Identity['Requests']['ListCompartmentsRequest'];

const id = '123';

const listCompartmentsRequest: ListCompartmentsRequest = {
  compartmentId: id,
  compartmentIdInSubtree: true,
};
```

And if you are targeting a type within a [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html), then you can use dot notation to access the nested type.